# ¿Cómo generar select a partir de un numero?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Amigos, necesito un código que sea capaz de generar un select apartir de un numero, así por ejemplo: tengo un código PHP que es capaz actualmente de devolverme la existencia de un producto, supongamos que la existencia del producto con código "000-001" es igual a "10", yo necesito que apartir de ese numero diez se genere un select de la siguiente manera:

```
<select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
    </select>
```

como pueden ver, va desde el 1 al 10 en su option, la verdad necesito ayuda con esto, saludos.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir lo que has intentado hasta el momento? En la sección [ask] se recomienda incluir un [mcve] ya que las preguntas que piden por código sin mostrar un esfuerzo mínimo no son bien recibidas. Si decides compartir tu código puedes [edit] tu pregunta en cualquier momento y enfocar tus dudas/preguntas al ejemplo mostrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
<select id="" name="">
<?php for($i=1;$i<=$existencias;$i++): ?>
    <option><?php echo $i?></option>
 <?php endfor; ?>
 </select>
```

También puedes checarlo en esta pagina [Dynamic Pages PHP](https://tutorials.supunkavinda.blog/php/in-html)